# Всегда ли нужно использовать UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING с аналитической функцией LAST_VALUE?

Tags: sql, oracle, оконные-функции

Всегда ли нужно использовать `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` с аналитической функцией `LAST_VALUE`?

Нашел пример, где без этой клаузы:

```
CREATE TABLE t (val) as
    SELECT level FROM dual CONNECT BY level<=3; 
 
SELECT 
    LAST_VALUE (val) OVER (ORDER BY val ASC) lastval
FROM t;

  LASTVAL
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Не дало ожидаемого результата, который должен был быть - выводить в каждой строке последнее значение.

Поэтому, нужно было использовать оконную клаузу.

```
SELECT 
    LAST_VALUE (val) OVER (ORDER BY val ASC 
        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) lastval
FROM t;

  LASTVAL
----------
         3
         3
         3
```

Поэтому стало интересно, нужно ли всегда с `LAST_VALUE` использовать оконную клаузу?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Do we always need to use UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING while using last_value() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69199866) от участника [@Abhilekh Dixit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16921198/abhilekh-dixit)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69199866

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае ответ - да, надо использовать оконную клаузу ([*windowing_clause*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056)).

Потому что окно по умолчанию - это диапазон между неограниченной предыдущей и текущей строкой:

> If you omit the windowing_clause entirely, then the default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

А последнее значение как раз и находится в текущей строке.

Исключением является случай, когда используется `IGNORE NULLS`, тогда оставить клаузу по умолчанию весьма полезно для получения последнего значения включая текущую, с не `NULL` значением. Например, как в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1330724).

Кстати, именно по этой причине многие обычно используют `FIRST_VALUE()` с обратной сортировкой:

```
select first_value (val) over (order by val DESC) lastval
from t;

   LASTVAL
----------
         3
         3
         3
```

Как в данном случае, то проще использовать `MAX`:

```
select max (val) over () lastval
from t;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69199882/6571020) от участника [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)</sub>