# Как заполнить предыдущим положительным значением если текущее пустое?

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос, таблицы

У меня есть таблица, в которой заполняются числовые данные в следующем порядке:

```
Это имя поля
1
2
0
0
0
3
0
4
0
0
0
5
```

Подскажите, как средствами SQL заполнить нулевые значения **предыдущим положительным** числом?

Т.е., нужно привести колонку к следующему виду:

```
Это имя поля
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
```

Comment: Чем определяется порядок?

Comment: указание конкретной СУБД в тэгах также сделает задачу более понятной

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На приведённых в вопросе данных -- никак, задача нерешаема.

> в которой заполняются числовые данные в следующем порядке

Порядок, в котором данные заполняются, не играет в дальнейшем никакой роли, он теряется. То есть, сегодня он `[1, 2, 0...]`, а завтра - `[5, 1, 0...]`.

Поэтому, чтобы решить задачу, требуется как минимум ещё один столбец для сортировки.

В примере ниже добавлен столбец `id`, по которому будет идти сортировка:

```
with t (id, val) as (
    select rownum, to_number (column_value)
    from xmlTable ('1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5')
    ) -- это тестовые данные для запроса ниже
 
select id, val oldval,
    last_value (case 
                when val>0 then val 
                end ignore nulls) over (order by id) newval 
from t
```

Теперь можно получить ожидаемый результат:

```
        ID     OLDVAL     NEWVAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         2          2          2
         3          0          2
         4          0          2
         5          0          2
         6          3          3
         7          0          3
         8          4          4
         9          0          4
        10          0          4
        11          0          4
        12          5          5
```

Comment: я уже давно решил этот вопрос самостоятельно, но ваш ответ хороший. Отмечу :) Спасибо!